# While reading from a file, choose specific fields and compare them with another file in Unix bash?

Tags: bash, scripting

I have a CSV file that contains the columns a,b,c,d and e and another file that contains column z. While reading line by line from the 1st file I want only fields c and d and at the same time I want to compare d with z from the second file.

z is a variable meaning, `for i in catfileb do ......`. Now if d is the same as z then display z, but if they are different, then always display "pin". But if z is for example longest or smallest display "lon" or "sma".

File a:

```
a b c d e
1 2 2 3 3
3 4 6 5 9
4 5 0 9 9
```

File b:

```
z
3
1
8
```

So c, d, and z are variables, so I was thinking of two loops. While reading line by line file a, get c and d, then compare with z.

Comment: Please include your desired output, it is very hard to understand what you mean otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to compare lines in `file b` to corresponding lines in `file a` (i.e. that both files have the same number of lines and you're comparing line-by-line), you can use a Perl script to do this for you:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
$file_a = "/path/to/file_a";
$file_b = "/path/to/file_b";
open $fa,'<',$file_a or die "Failed to open file $file_a: $!\n";
open $fb,'<',$file_b or die "Failed to open file $file_b: $!\n";
@file_a = <$fa>;
@file_b = <$fb>;
close $fa;
close $fb;
for (0..$#file_a){
    ($col_c,$col_d) = (split / /,$file_a[$_])[2,3];
    $col_z = $file_b[$_];
    $to_display = "$col_c $col_d";
    if($col_z eq $col_d){
        $to_display .= " $col_z";
    }
    else{
        $to_display .= " pin";
        if ($col_z gt $col_c and $col_z gt $col_d ){
            $to_display .= " lon";
        }
        elsif($col_z lt $col_c and $col_z lt $col_d) {
            $to_display .= " sma";
        }
    }
    print "$to_display\n";
}
```

Save the above file as `/path/to/myscript` (after modifying the locations of `file_a` and `file_b` to your true locations), then make it executable: `chmod +x /path/to/myscript` and finally invoke it: `$ /path/to/myscript`.

Comment: appreciate it but i want to use loops instead so if i can find a way to get only 2 fields of file a while reading it and then compare one of them to a field of another file

Comment: @user2613272 Unless I misunderstand you, that's exactly what's happening in the above code with the `for (0..$#file_a)` loop.

Comment: All perl code should have `use strict`, and it should be able to compile with `strict`.

Comment: @jordanm This is highly debatable at best. While I agree with the principle in general and use it for all my scripts, I don't use it for one-off, ad-hoc code.

Answer (score 1):

As I said in my comment, I am not entirely sure what you are trying to do, you seem to want to always print fields `c` and `d` and to compare *only* `d` with `z`. If so, the solution below should work.

```
$ paste a b | awk '{print $3,$4,$6}' | head -n 1; paste a b | tail -n +2 |
   while read a b c d e z; do 
    echo -n "$c $d"; 
    if [ "$d" -lt "$z" ]; then 
      echo "pin sma"; 
    elif [ "$d" -gt "$z" ]; then 
      echo "pin lon"; 
    else echo $z; 
    fi; 
   done
```

Run on the example files you have provided, this gives:

```
c d z
2 33
6 5pin lon
0 9pin lon
```

#### Explanation

Since you want an arithmetic comparison, the headers will break the script. However, I imagine you would like to have them in the final output. So, first I print them:

```
paste a b | awk '{print $3,$4,$6}' | head -n 1;
```

So, now we want to process the rest of the fields, skipping the header. So, we [`paste`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/paste/) the files again, skip the headers (`tail -n +2`) and process the fields.

Comment: 1.please note that i don't have the same number of lines in both files.

Comment: 2. second i have the files but i don't know how to assign certain fields into variables , and then use these variables . Basically at the end , what i want is yes to print cd_z

Comment: each line in d should be compared with every line in z

Comment: i don't want to use perl , i'm writing in bash and thank you

Comment: and based on your code how does it know where to get the variables from which files ?

Comment: i don't want to actually print literally cd_z but i want to print only the variables that are inside them.

Comment: just to make myself clear 3 in d should be compared with 3, 1, and 8 in z same for 5 should be compared with 3 , 1 , an 8

Comment: it's not an arithmetic comparison , i used numbers just to make things easier, so no need to use lt or gt; longest and smallest are just examples or words

Comment: @user2613272 then please do as I asked in my other comment and post an example of your real data and your desired output. It is very hard to understand what you are trying to do. Also remember that in many languages (bash included) comparing numbers or strings is not the same thing. If you don't want an arithmetic comparison what exactly do you want to compare? The string length? The strings alphabetically?